# Magento - Prototype.js and jQuery issue - Add to cart Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs, magento-1.8

I'm build store with Magento and ran into a serious problem with jQuery and Prototype.js

I imported/rendered new JS files as written in Mastering Magento Theme Design book, but on the product view page the add to cart button doesn't work.

when I click on the button the following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined onclick
```

I left everything the way it is in JS that are imported by Magento and added only these files:

```
default/js/jquery.min.js">
default/js/bootstrap.min.js">
default/js/jquery.scripts.js">
default/js/chosen.jquery.min.js">
```

inside jquery.scripts.js file I have:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(fucntion(){

});
```

and I have no idea what is wrong with it.
I've been looking for about 2 hours now but didn't find any wise solution or suggestion.

the problems disappear when I remove jquery.min.js file only.

Comment: are you able to load the jQuery scripts before prototype.js and call noConflict before protoype loads?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your jquery file above prototype.js file.

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is that when I manually add prototype.js at the end of the imports of JS files all the rest of JS files that magento includes fire errors. and to answer question, no I do removeItem and then after jQuery addItem of prototype.js but prototype.js is being added before jQuery. Is there any normal solution without headache?

Comment: @charlietfl - I did manage to add jQuery above prototype but now when I open the menu (with click) and the close - it disappears. on closing the menu dropdown <li> has style="display:none;" Do you have any idea why now it puts display to none?

Answer (score 0):

jquery conflict with Prototype in magento:

Simplest solution is to add at the end of your main jquery file.

jQuery.noConflict();

Or create your custom js file and add this line and also include this file after main js.